# Counting data with Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following table that has several columns and is populated by various data:

[image: pivot table]

What I am trying to achieve is I need to count of the number of times the MAKE "**Ishida**" shows up in a particular year such as "**2018**".But I also need to exclude a number of brands in the *MAKE* column:

```
NCR
SCALE WEIGHING SYSTEMS
HANSON
NCR
DATALOGIC SCANNING INC
PSC - SCANNING, INC.
A&&D
PSC INC
CITIZEN SCALE, INC
DETECTO
ZEBRA TECHNOLOGIES CORP
A&D
BRECKNELL
ZEBRA
AT&T
DEFIANCE
OHAUS
HOWE RICH
SANITARY
CHATILLON
DATALOGIC USA INC
ATRON SYSTEM, INC
MAGELLAN
DATALOGIC  ADC INC
CCI
TERAOKA
GRS
WEIGH TRONIX
KUBOTA
AV WEIGH TRONIX
MOTOROLA SOLUTIONS, INC
CITIZEN SCALE, INC
AND
PSC - SCANNING, INC.
TERAOKA
```

I import the whole data:

[image: pivot table import]

But I do not how to go from here though.

[image: pivot table filter]

So the end result is I need to see

***2018 - Number of Ishida***

***2017 - Number of Ishida***

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: good start, now click on the down arrow by the make filter (cell B1) and select Ishida. Next, in the right pivot table fields panel, drag the year/date field into the row section. You could filter just for 2017 and 2018 by clicking on the down arrow. Now you know as much about pivot tables as me :-)

Comment: @gns100 but how can I filter out the list of brands I do not need there. Because I need to get the number of Ishida scales out there and then the total number of scales there. But those brands do not make the scales I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer, but it is based the OP comment. This is a screenshot of the what you would probably see when you click on the down arrow. Scroll down until you see 'Ishida' (that is my highlight) and click on it.

[image]

As my above comment mentions, drag the date field to the rows and excel should auto create year groupings for you. Let me know if this helps.